# I want to show a another dialog box with same styling once button clicked on first dialog box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I clicked login button when call if from a mobile screen , i ll display a dialog box with a continue button once user clicks it i ll show another content on same dialog box.

```js
    $(document).on("click", "#btn", function() {
      var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      if (true) {
        $(document).on("click", "#btn", function() {
          $('<div></div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Confirmation",
            classes: {
              'ui-dialog-titlebar-close': 'hidden',
            },
            open: function() {
              var markup = 'Hello World';
              $(this).html(markup);
            },
            buttons: {
              Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
            }
          }); //end confirm dialog

        });
      } else {
        alert('false');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Luck

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    //style all the dialogue
    $( function() {
        $(".dialog_help").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx'
        });
    });
    
    //opens the appropriate dialog
    $( function() {
        $(".opener").click(function () {
            //takes the ID of appropriate dialogue
            var id = $(this).data('id');
           //close dialogue
            $("#dialog_1").dialog("close");
            //open dialogue
            $(id).dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>

<em class='opener' data-id='#dialog_1' style='cursor: pointer;'> Help 1</em>
<div class='dialog_help' id='dialog_1' title='Dialog Box'>
    <p>Dialog Box 1</p>
    <em class='opener' data-id='#dialog_2' style='cursor: pointer;'> Help 2</em></p>
</div>
<div class='dialog_help' id='dialog_2' title='Dialog Box'>
    <p>Dialog Box 2</p>
</div>
```